# gnocchi-api running error, Address already in use

Tags: openstack, telemetry, ceilometer

When i install Ceilometer and on the stage of "Verify operation" on OpenStack Installation Tutorials， i run command following，But it's not success.

```
[root@controller3 gnocchi]# gnocchi resource list  --type image
Unable to establish connection to http://localhost:8041/v1/resource/image?: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8041): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/resource/image (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2ff4950>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

When i finished the gnocchi installation and run `gnocchi-upgrade`, that's all right.
But next, when i run `gnocchi-api`, the `gnocchi-api.log` show WSGI  `Address already in use`.
Could you tell me how to solve it ? Thanks !

#### gnocchi-api.log:

```
2017-08-03 21:40:09,020 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: ********************************************************************************
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: Configuration options gathered from:
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: command line args: []
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: config files: ['/etc/gnocchi/gnocchi.conf']
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: ================================================================================
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: config_dir                     = []
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: config_file                    = ['/etc/gnocchi/gnocchi.conf']
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: debug                          = True
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: log_dir                        = /var/log/gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: log_file                       = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: syslog_log_facility            = user
2017-08-03 21:40:09,021 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: use_journal                    = False
2017-08-03 21:40:09,022 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: use_syslog                     = False
2017-08-03 21:40:09,022 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: verbose                        = True
2017-08-03 21:40:09,022 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.archive_policy_name     = low
2017-08-03 21:40:09,022 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.creator                 = :
2017-08-03 21:40:09,022 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.flush_delay             = 10.0
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.host                    = controller3
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.port                    = 8125
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.project_id              = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.resource_id             = 83746b69-87e8-4ee2-b9af-39769cc32b75
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: statsd.user_id                 = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.ceph_conffile         = /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
2017-08-03 21:40:09,023 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.ceph_keyring          = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,024 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.ceph_pool             = gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,024 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.ceph_secret           = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,024 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.ceph_timeout          = 30
2017-08-03 21:40:09,024 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.ceph_username         = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,024 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.driver                = file
2017-08-03 21:40:09,024 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.file_basepath         = /var/lib/gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,025 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.redis_url             = redis://localhost:6379/
2017-08-03 21:40:09,025 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.s3_access_key_id      = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,025 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.s3_bucket_prefix      = gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,025 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.s3_check_consistency_timeout = 60.0
2017-08-03 21:40:09,025 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.s3_endpoint_url       = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,025 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.s3_region_name        = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,026 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.s3_secret_access_key  = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,026 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_auth_version    = 1
2017-08-03 21:40:09,026 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_authurl         = http://localhost:8080/auth/v1.0
2017-08-03 21:40:09,026 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_container_prefix = gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,026 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_endpoint_type   = publicURL
2017-08-03 21:40:09,027 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_key             = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,027 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_preauthtoken    = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,027 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_preauthurl      = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,027 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_project_domain_name = Default
2017-08-03 21:40:09,027 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_project_name    = 
2017-08-03 21:40:09,027 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_timeout         = 300
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_user            = admin:admin
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: incoming.swift_user_domain_name = Default
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: metricd.metric_cleanup_delay   = 300
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: metricd.metric_processing_delay = 60
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: metricd.metric_reporting_delay = 120
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: metricd.processing_replicas    = 3
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: metricd.worker_sync_rate       = 30
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: metricd.workers                = 4
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.backend               = sqlalchemy
2017-08-03 21:40:09,028 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.connection            = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.connection_debug      = 0
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.connection_trace      = False
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.db_inc_retry_interval = True
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.db_max_retries        = 20
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.db_max_retry_interval = 10
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.db_retry_interval     = 1
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.idle_timeout          = 3600
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.max_overflow          = 50
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.max_pool_size         = 5
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.max_retries           = 10
2017-08-03 21:40:09,029 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.min_pool_size         = 1
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.mysql_sql_mode        = TRADITIONAL
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.pool_timeout          = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.retry_interval        = 10
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.slave_connection      = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.sqlite_db             = oslo.sqlite
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.sqlite_synchronous    = True
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: database.use_db_reconnect      = False
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.aggregation_workers_number = 1
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.ceph_conffile          = /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.ceph_keyring           = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.ceph_pool              = gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.ceph_secret            = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,030 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.ceph_timeout           = 30
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.ceph_username          = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.coordination_url       = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.driver                 = file
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.file_basepath          = /var/lib/gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.redis_url              = redis://localhost:6379/
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.s3_access_key_id       = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.s3_bucket_prefix       = gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.s3_check_consistency_timeout = 60.0
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.s3_endpoint_url        = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.s3_region_name         = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.s3_secret_access_key   = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_auth_version     = 1
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_authurl          = http://localhost:8080/auth/v1.0
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_container_prefix = gnocchi
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_endpoint_type    = publicURL
2017-08-03 21:40:09,031 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_key              = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_preauthtoken     = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_preauthurl       = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_project_domain_name = Default
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_project_name     = None
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_timeout          = 300
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_user             = admin:admin
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: storage.swift_user_domain_name = Default
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: indexer.url                    = ****
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: api.auth_mode                  = keystone
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: api.max_limit                  = 1000
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: api.paste_config               = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnocchi/rest/api-paste.ini
2017-08-03 21:40:09,032 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: api.refresh_timeout            = 10
2017-08-03 21:40:09,033 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: archive_policy.default_aggregation_methods = ['mean', 'min', 'max', 'sum', 'std', 'count']
2017-08-03 21:40:09,033 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: oslo_policy.policy_default_rule = default
2017-08-03 21:40:09,033 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: oslo_policy.policy_dirs        = ['policy.d']
2017-08-03 21:40:09,033 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: oslo_policy.policy_file        = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnocchi/rest/policy.json
2017-08-03 21:40:09,033 [6098] DEBUG    gnocchi.service: ********************************************************************************
2017-08-03 21:40:10,538 [6098] INFO     gnocchi.rest.app: WSGI config used: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnocchi/rest/api-paste.ini
2017-08-03 21:40:11,441 [6098] WARNING  keystonemiddleware.auth_token: AuthToken middleware is set with keystone_authtoken.service_token_roles_required set to False. This is backwards compatible but deprecated behaviour. Please set this to True.
2017-08-03 21:40:11,474 [6098] WARNING  keystonemiddleware.auth_token: Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required; clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint
2017-08-03 21:40:11,514 [6098] CRITICAL root: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnocchi-api", line 34, in <module>
    server = wss.make_server('', args.port, build_wsgi_app())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 144, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 48, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

#### gnocchi.conf

```
[DEFAULT]
debug = true
verbose = true
log_dir = /var/log/gnocchi

[api]
workers = 4                                                                            
auth_mode = keystone
paste_config = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnocchi/rest/api-paste.ini

[indexer]
url = mysql+pymysql://gnocchi:pass123456@controller3/gnocchi?charset=utf8

[keystone_authtoken]
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://controller3:5000/v3
project_domain_name = Default
user_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
username = gnocchi
password = pass123456
interface = internalURL
region_name = RegionOne
```

#### ceilometer.conf

```
[DEFAULT]
meter_dispatchers=gnocchi
event_dispatchers=gnocchi
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:pass123456@controller3

[dispatcher_gnocchi]
filter_service_activity = False
archive_policy = low

[service_credentials]
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://controller3:5000/v3
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = ceilometer
password = pass123456
interface = internalURL
region_name = RegionOne
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the port being used is: 8125. You'll want to see if anything else is using that port on the server.

> > lsof -p 8125

If another service is using the port 8125 then you may want to modify the port used in the gnocchi configuration (/etc/gnocchi/gnocchi.conf) to 8041. After updating the port - try restarting the service. Let's see if the same error comes up.

If it still isn't working then it is possible that it is hitting a bug that was reported. If modifying the port in the configuration file is still failing, then it may be attempting to bind to 8000 still. To fix this we'll need to check out the service script. Here's an invalid bug that goes over a similar issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnocchi/+bug/1672446

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to run lsof -p 8125, it is no output. And i modify the port to 8041 in gnocchi.conf, but the log show the same error. The solution is  modify the default port to 8042 in `aodh-api`(`/usr/bin/aodh-api`), and modify the default 8000 port to 8041 in `gnocchi-api`(`/usr/bin/gnocchi-api`) it works normally.

Comment: And you must add `export OS_AUTH_TYPE=password` to your `admin-openrc` script before run `ceilometer-upgrade --skip-metering-database`